# Frama-C Neon missing C library files?

Tags: c, neon, frama-c

I've successfully compiled Frama-C Neon (Ubuntu) along with Why2, Why3 and Coq.

With previous versions (Nitrogen) it was possible to choose a particular heap model, by defining some symbols like:

```
#define FRAMA_C_MALLOC_HEAP
```

and so on.

The [Frama-C Neon user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/value-analysis-Neon-20140301.pdf) suggests to include the file `share/malloc.c`, but I can't find it.

- Frama-C Nitrogen contains both `share/malloc.c` and`share/libc/stdlib.c` (including the latter worked fine);
- Frama-C Fluorine 3 contains `share/stdlib.c` only;
- Frama-C Fluorine 2 contains neither ;
- Frama-C Neon contains neither;

Moreover the [Fluorine 3 changelog](http://frama-c.com/Changelog.html#Fluorine-20130601) lists "Add missing C library files."

Are `FRAMA_C_MALLOC_*` symbols deprecated or is the Neon source distribution somewhat incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some files in relation to modeling dynamic memory allocation were removed from the Neon Frama-C release.